# Is it possible to use the .NET Trace to output it to a tcp/ip listener?

Tags: c#, .net, trace, diagnostics, azure-diagnostics

If i'm using `Trace.XXX` in my .NET code, is it possible to use to send this data to a separate trace listener via `tcp/ip`.

Also, this is for a *worker role* in Windows Azure, btw.

Sorta similar to how nLog or log4net can do this.

Comment: I don't believe there is one in framework, but should be pretty straightforward to write one (as long as you figured out sending part). What exactly causing problem in your case? Assuming you've read on [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) and related clasess...

Comment: I'm just having a woeful experience with Azure + logging any tracing information :( As in, not getting any tracedata and i'm sick of reading out of date blogs etc about this and was trying to think of an other way around this.

Comment: If you are debugging, have you looked at the Azure SDK 2.2 feature of remote debugging where you can attach to the remote cloud service process?

Comment: Yes - i sure have! but this is a bit different .. meaning .. i don't want to PAUSE the code (imagine live!).